# Obtaining standard port for arbitrary protocols in PHP

Tags: php, url, protocols, port

I'm looking for a function that will accept a string representing the scheme portion of a URL (e.g., "http", "https", "ftp", etc.) and return the standard port.  It might be used like this:

```
echo get_port_from_protocol("http");  // 80
```

As a last resort, I suppose I could write something to parse through `/etc/services` (assuming I only need to run under UNIX-like operating systems).

But surely there must be something built-in to PHP, no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int getservbyname ( string $service , string $protocol )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getservbyname.php

So essentially you could do

```
echo getservbyname("http", "tcp");
```